# Can you initiate a Twilio phone call with answering machine detection using Twiml?

Tags: twilio

It appears that you can only do this with the REST API but not with the  Twiml keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641643/use-ifmachine-in-twiml-when-using-dial/24775220#24775220

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't make outbound interactive calls at all using TwiML. You can certainly use the Dial verb to connect a caller to another party, (http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), but you aren't interacting with the caller/callee for the duration of that dialed call (i.e., you can't Say, Gather, etc...). The interaction picks up only after the Dial-ed call ends.

In short, initiate the call using the REST API, and then you can continue the interaction using TwiML as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It is done via the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection).

For example, the `MachineDetection` parameter can be `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

Using new AMD [looks like this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/introducing-new-answering-machine-detection.html):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```