# Use IfMachine in TwiML when using <Dial>

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to use the `Dial` verb in conjunction with the `IfMachine` parameter?  I don't see anything on the dial verb page (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) which indicates the `IfMachine` parameter can be used or whether it will be passed to the resulting Action parameter.

I found this post [Detecting if an answering service picks up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834089/detecting-if-an-answering-service-picks-up), and the answer says "put the IfMachine parameter in your TwiML", but I don't see any examples of the `IfMachine` parameter being used in TwiML.  I've only seen examples of it being used with the REST API.

I'm trying to have my application redirect a call, then if that redirected call was picked up by an answering machine to then send a text message.  Ideally the incoming call TwiML would look something like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial action="/sendSmsIfMachine.cshtml" method="POST" ifMachine="Continue">
    555-5555
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then my sendSmsIfMachine page would have something like:

```
@{
   Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
   if(Response["AnsweredBy"] == "machine")
   {
      var twimlResponse = new TwilioResponse();
      twimlResponse.Message("You got a voicemail", new { to = "555-5556" });
      Response.Write(twimlResponse.ToString();
   }
 }
```

When I tried this, the resulting request made to sendSmsIfMachine.cshtml did not include the AnsweredBy parameter according to to the Twilio log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No** Twiml Doesn't support (AMD) `ifMachine` parameter. I've contacted Twilio about this issue and below is there response.

> Hi Sisir,
>
> Thanks for the question. No, AMD is not supported by TwiML, only by
>   the API. This means that IfMachine and AnsweredBy are only valid for
>   calls initiated by the REST API.
>
> This was a deliberate exclusion when we released AMD. The way machine
>   detection works is it listens to the answering party for a second
>   before connecting the call. Then if it hears audio patterns that sound
>   like a human, it lets the calls connect.
>
> The problem with calls on  is that there is usually a user on
>   the line already waiting for the called party to pick up. So, if the
>   machine detection "eats" the first second of the call, the person
>   already on the phone doesn't hear the called party say "Hello." This
>   causes a bit of an awkward silence.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Twilio Customer Support

So, if you want to use there AMD feature you **MUST** use [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection).

Comment: I've had a similar issue and just posted a question. Can the REST API be used to connect two callers?

Comment: *two callers*, if they both are calling then you should try using conference feature.

Comment: How come we can't use AMD in TwiML anymore?

Comment: AFAIK It was never implemented in TwiML