# Twilio PHP Library and answering machine detection

Tags: php, twilio

I am using the twilio PHP REST Library and trying to determine if it is possible to use the Answering Machine Detection described [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine).

I am working on something similar to the broadcast example they provide [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/broadcast) and would like to ensure that messages played back for the user are complete when left on the voice mail.

I think the relevant section of code is here, but I havent been able to determine what if any parameter could be utilized or if you must call the REST API directly and not use the Twilio provided library, as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641643/use-ifmachine-in-twiml-when-using-dial?lq=1) .

```
$client->account->calls->create($number,$output, $url);
```

Comment: Submitted a support request at Twilio as well.  Will update if they provide information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting twilio support the answer seems pretty straight forward.  For any of the extra parameters that you may want to call add in an array with the appropriate values.

```
$client->account->calls->create($number,$output, $url,array('IfMachine' =>'Continue'));
```

A full list of parameters can be used is located here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional

Comment: Now there is enhanced AMD: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection