# Bypass personal voicemail to Twilio Voicemail Twimlet

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have a basic call forward using Twilio's  verb, but am running into trouble with voicemail. Instead of the receiving user's personal voicemail, I want to reroute to a Twimlet that records the voicemail and emails it. With my current code, I'm altering the 'timeout' parameter between 3-10 seconds with mixed results. Sometimes the Twimlet voicemail picks up first, and sometimes the call gets picked up then the Twimlet fires off on a live call. Is there some way to detect a voicemail is about to pick up and redirect to the twimlet with consistency?

```
post '/number/forward/:sid' do
  @number = Number.find_by_twilio_sid(params[:sid])
  @forward = Number.find_by_parent_id(@number.id) 

  if @forward.extension == nil
    Twilio::TwiML.build do |r|
      r.Dial @forward.number, :callerId => @number.number, :timeout => '7', :action => "http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=email%40gmail.com&Message=Thank%20you%20for%20calling%2C%20please%20leave%20a%20message.&T", :method => "GET"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Whilst we do have experimental [answering machine detection in the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection), there is no affordance for that within TwiML. There was another question/answer on SO that answers this better. Please see: [Use IfMachine in TwiML when using <Dial>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641643/use-ifmachine-in-twiml-when-using-dial)