# Using Answering machine detection on Twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I would like to implement Answering machine detection in TwiML to prevent voicemail answer the phone.
I have the following TwiML bin configuration for my Twilio number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial timeout="10">UK_NUMBER</Dial>
  <Dial>US_NUMBER</Dial>
</Response>
```

According to this stackoverflow request I can use AMD only with REST API and not TwiML.
[Use IfMachine in TwiML when using <Dial>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641643/use-ifmachine-in-twiml-when-using-dial)

However this request is quite old,do you know if it is possible to use Answering machine detection in TwiML now?
If yes, please provide me with an example.

Or if it is not possible could you give please me any other options to solve the problem using TwiML?

Comment: You can't implement AMD in TwiML. Could you possibly tell me what your use case is so I can suggest an alternative though? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Philnash, thanks for the response.
I have the Twiml Bin for inbound calls described above. The problem is when my UK_NUMBER is switched off the voicemail answers an inbound call so, the inbound call never goes to my US_NUMBER. 
I would like to skip the voicemail somehow, so basically I want inbound calls never go to voicemail, they should go to US_NUMBER when the UK_NUMBER is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolay, as mentioned above, our enhanced AMD is still available just through the REST API with the [`MachineDetection`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection#rest-api-parameters) parameter.