# TwiML Answering Machine Detection for Masked Calling

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm using Twilio to connect my "users" with my on-call "staff", but I want to use masked calling as the staff are remote and I need to track how long the calls lasted, so don't want them having each others numbers.

This is all working perfectly using TwiML, but I have the issue that my staff may not answer a call, and the user will be sent to their answering machine. My server will then detect the call was longer than 0 seconds, and will charge the user even though they only got through to the answering machine... So the Answering Machine Detection sounds like what I need: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection

However this doesn't give any examples for use with TwiML.
It would seem based off this question that it is not usable? ([Using Answering machine detection on Twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596203/using-answering-machine-detection-on-twiml))

So is there any update since the linked answer? Or is it possible for me to do the masked calls without TwiML? Does the `response.SetOption` method provide anything useful for this or will I have to live without Answering Machine Detection?

At present my code that generates the TwiML for the TwiML App is like this:

```
   public static string TwiMLDial(string maskedNumber, string to, string callCompleteURL)
    {
        var response = new Twilio.TwiML.VoiceResponse();
        var dial = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Dial(action: new Uri(callCompleteURL), callerId: maskedNumber);
        dial.Number(to);
        response.Gather();
        response.Dial(dial);
        return response.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're right, you can't use the Answering Machine detection from TwiML. As an alternative, what you could do is put the dialling user straight into a queue (using [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue)) and then dial your staff using the REST API and Answering machine detection. If the staff answer the call, connect them to the dialler by [`<Dial>`ling the `<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hey thanks, sounds like what I need. Will give it a go and let you know!

Comment: I can't seem to find the correct place to put my "callCompleteURL" now. If I put it on the Enqueue action it comes back when the client leaves the queue (with duration of 0 seconds). If I Put it on the staff dial, it also says a duration of 0 seconds....

Comment: I would place it as the `<Dial>`'s `action` attribute. Is that what you've got? Alternatively, you can set a [`StatusCallback` parameter on the REST API request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#optional-parameters) that you can use to tell when then call is over.

Comment: Yeah that is where I had it, using `DialCallDuration` and `CallDuration` both are 0. StatusCallback seems to give me the full length of the user's call, including time spent in queue. I think I'll just record the time myself between  callbacks of the dial `actionURL` and the queue `url`